# Duplicate column getting added after groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply 2 groupby operations consecutively on a single column of a dataframe, once after applying groupby operation one more columns is getting added, which not allowing me to apply second groupby,

i have searched similar question, could'nt find. is it a normal operation or how to eliminate extra column in groupby operation.I have tried changing `as_index`, `group_keys` options,both did'nt work.

df1

```
CAT CODE    CODE1   SUB
0   NaN NaN NaN 123
1   SKU NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN 1000123 NaN NaN
3   NaN 1000234 NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN 456
5   LIQ NaN NaN NaN
6   NaN NaN 1000345 NaN
7   NaN NaN 1000534 NaN
8   NaN NaN 1000433 NaN
```

expecting to do

```
df1.groupby(df1['SUB'].ffill()).ffill().groupby('SUB').bfill()
```

current output after groupby ( Extra 'SUB' column added)

```
df1.groupby(df1.SUB.ffill()).fill()


    SUB CAT CODE CODE1     SUB
0   123 NaN NaN  NaN       123
1   123 SKU NaN  NaN       123
2   123 SKU 1000123 NaN    123
3   123 SKU 1000234 NaN    123
4   456 NaN NaN  NaN       456
5   456 LIQ NaN  NaN       456
6   456 LIQ NaN 1000345    456
7   456 LIQ NaN 1000534    456
8   456 LIQ NaN 1000433    456
```

Expected output

```
    SUB CAT CODE    CODE1
0   123 NaN NaN     NaN 
1   123 SKU NaN     NaN 
2   123 SKU 1000123 NaN 
3   123 SKU 1000234 NaN 
4   456 NaN NaN     NaN
5   456 LIQ NaN     NaN
6   456 LIQ NaN   1000345
7   456 LIQ NaN   1000534
8   456 LIQ NaN   1000433
```

Comment: Yes @anky_91, explicitly we can bring out :) . i would like to know whether pandas groupby allowed to give such duplicate column or possibility of removing through [groupby optioins](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: i see. let me look up. :)

Comment: i found this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21521

Comment: ohh Bug of pandas then :0 , please add it to your answer , i will accept it and close the question.

Comment: likewise @Naga Kiran . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up online i found that there is a bug reported in github with this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21521

as a workaround , try with :

```
df.groupby(df.SUB.ffill())[df.columns.difference(['SUB'])].ffill()
```

---

```
     SUB  CAT       CODE      CODE1
0  123.0  NaN        NaN        NaN
1  123.0  SKU        NaN        NaN
2  123.0  SKU  1000123.0        NaN
3  123.0  SKU  1000234.0        NaN
4  456.0  NaN        NaN        NaN
5  456.0  LIQ        NaN        NaN
6  456.0  LIQ        NaN  1000345.0
7  456.0  LIQ        NaN  1000534.0
8  456.0  LIQ        NaN  1000433.0
```

Comment: thanks for answer @anky_91, explicitly we can bring out :) . i would like to know whether pandas groupby allowed to give such duplicate column or possibility of removing through [groupby optioins](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) .

Answer (score 1):

Use `.fillna` specifying the method. `.fillna(method='ffill')`, is synonymous with `.ffill`, but it isn't bugged for groupings.

```
df.groupby(df.SUB.ffill()).fillna(method='ffill')

   CAT       CODE      CODE1    SUB
0  NaN        NaN        NaN  123.0
1  SKU        NaN        NaN  123.0
2  SKU  1000123.0        NaN  123.0
3  SKU  1000234.0        NaN  123.0
4  NaN        NaN        NaN  456.0
5  LIQ        NaN        NaN  456.0
6  LIQ        NaN  1000345.0  456.0
7  LIQ        NaN  1000534.0  456.0
8  LIQ        NaN  1000433.0  456.0
```

Comment: sure i will incorporate. [.fillna] method working fine without duplicating the column like [.ffill]. Thanks for the response @ALollz,